# Amazon - can't connect to instance behind VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

For testing purposes, I set up a VPC on Amazon and created an instance within the VPC. I've added a gateway for the 0.0.0.0/0 address to the attached routing table, and given the instance an elastic IP address. I'm unable to ssh or ping it, even when I set the security group to allow all traffic. I must be missing something obvious. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when I created the instance, I accepted the default security group, which only allows access from a specific IP address. When I added another instance, I created it with a security group which allowed all traffic, and I was able to ping it.